# How can I verify if an AD account is locked?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to know if it is possible to verify if a specific AD account is locked.

The command [`Get-ADUser`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617241.aspx) does not return this parameter :

```
 -------------------------- EXAMPLE 3 --------------------------

 Command Prompt: C:\PS>
 Get-ADUser GlenJohn -Properties * 


  - Surname : John 
  - Name : Glen John
  - UserPrincipalName : jglen
  - GivenName : Glen
  - Enabled : False
  - SamAccountName : GlenJohn
  - ObjectClass :
  - user SID :S-1-5-21-2889043008-4136710315-2444824263-3544
  - ObjectGUID :e1418d64-096c-4cb0-b903-ebb66562d99d
  - DistinguishedName : CN=Glen John,OU=NorthAmerica,OU=Sales,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM

 Description :
 -----------

 Get all properties of the user with samAccountName 'GlenJohn'.

 --------------------------END EXAMPLE --------------------------
```

Is there an other way to get this information ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `LockedOut` property is what you are looking for among all the properties you returned. You are only seeing incomplete output in TechNet. The information is still there. You can isolate that one property using `Select-Object`

```
Get-ADUser matt -Properties * | Select-Object LockedOut

LockedOut
---------
False
```

The link you referenced doesn't contain this information which is obviously misleading. Test the command with your own account and you will see much more information.

Note: Try to avoid `-Properties *`. While it is great for simple testing it can make queries, especially ones with multiple accounts, unnecessarily slow. So, in this case, since you only need `lockedout`:

```
Get-ADUser matt -Properties LockedOut | Select-Object LockedOut
```

Comment: Why use the wildcard on the properties parameter if you already know what you are looking for. 

Try this 

(Get-Aduser matt -Properties LockedOut).LockedOut

Comment: @JoeRod Yes. That is the point I cover in the second half of the answer. Minus the property expansion but that is a minor point and not the focus of the answer.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to check via command line , then use command "net user username /DOMAIN"

[image]

Comment: I vote for this, it doesn't need any modules

Answer (score 15):

Here's another one:

```
PS> Search-ADAccount -Locked | Select Name, LockedOut, LastLogonDate

Name                                       LockedOut LastLogonDate
----                                       --------- -------------
Yxxxxxxx                                        True 14/11/2014 10:19:20
Bxxxxxxx                                        True 18/11/2014 08:38:34
Administrator                                   True 03/11/2014 20:32:05
```

Other parameters worth mentioning:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive

Get-Help Search-ADAccount -ShowWindow
```

Answer (score 4):

I found also this list of property flags: [How to use the UserAccountControl flags](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144)

```
SCRIPT                         0x0001            1
ACCOUNTDISABLE                 0x0002            2
HOMEDIR_REQUIRED               0x0008            8
LOCKOUT                        0x0010           16
PASSWD_NOTREQD                 0x0020           32
PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE             0x0040           64
ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PWD_ALLOWED     0x0080          128
TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT         0x0100          256
NORMAL_ACCOUNT                 0x0200          512
INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT      0x0800         2048
WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT      0x1000         4096
SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT           0x2000         8192
DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD           0x10000       65536
MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT              0x20000      131072
SMARTCARD_REQUIRED             0x40000      262144
TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION         0x80000      524288
NOT_DELEGATED                  0x100000    1048576
USE_DES_KEY_ONLY               0x200000    2097152
DONT_REQ_PREAUTH               0x400000    4194304
PASSWORD_EXPIRED               0x800000    8388608
TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION 0x1000000  16777216
PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT        0x04000000 67108864
```

You must make a binary-AND of property `userAccountControl` with `0x002`. In order to get all locked (i.e. disabled) accounts you can filter on this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```

For operator `1.2.840.113556.1.4.803` see [LDAP Matching Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223367.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This [ScriptingGuy guest post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/27/use-powershell-to-find-the-location-of-a-locked-out-user/) links to a script by a Microsoft Powershell Expert can help you find this information, but to fully audit why it was locked and which machine triggered the lock you probably need to turn on additional levels of auditing via GPO.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LockedOutLocation-b2fd0cab#content